# How to combine the tee command with interactive scripts to log the results?

Tags: linux, tty, tee

From some time usually record long outputs with `tee` to later `less` them, this is awesome to review `configure` and `make` outputs and such, but fails when the script or program is installation like, asking for human input.

This [Write a log file of a user interactive process using tee?](http://tinyurl.com/meds7ln) is the more relevant related question search engines give, but dont want to solve it using screen as it is said there. Even though all of this is being done inside a tmux session, prefer to not rely on the *insert your screen emulation solution here* to solve this.

Unlike in that case, here dont mind the user input, but i think a program fails at some point and i can not look where. System is with no X suite, so can not scroll back to view the entire output with a *konsole* or alike.

Anybody got ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "script" - typescript of terminal session.

```
$ script --help
```

From the man page of `script` :

```
 script makes a typescript of everything printed on your
 terminal.  It is useful for students who need a hard‐
 copy record of an interactive session as proof of an
 assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out
 later with lpr(1).
```

Comment: okay this is giving me much more information than needed but gets it done.